# Rounding off numbers using R to draw graphs

Tags: r, plot

I have below data in a CSV file.

```
id,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
30,0.841933670833,0.842101814883,0.842759547545,1.88961562347,1.99808377527,0.841933670833
40,1.47207692205,1.48713866811,1.48717177671,1.48729643008,1.48743226992,1.48713866811
50,0.823895293045,0.900091982861,0.900710334491,0.901274168324,0.901413662472,0.901413662472
```

I need to draw graphs sharing "id" as X-axis. i.e - f1 vs id, f2 vs id etc.

My question is;how do I round off numbers like this, 0.841933670833 to  nearest one and tenth and draw graphs.

whenever I tried to load these values in to data frames, I got scientific numbers with "e" values such as 8.229847e-07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever I tried to load these values in to data frames, I got scientific numbers with "e" values such as 8.229847e-07 That is just formatting.

No need to worry. By default R **prints** numbers with 7 digits. Beyond that scientific notation is used. But you lose no precision, as it is just about printing.

> How do I round off numbers like this, 0.841933670833 to nearest one and tenth

Try `round(0.841933670833, digits = 1)`. Let's suppose your data frame after reading in ".csv" is `dat`, you want to take out `f1`, `f2`, ... and do rounding.

```
rdat <- round(dat[-1], 1)
#      f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6
#  1  0.8 0.8 0.8 1.9 2.0 0.8
#  2  1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#  3  0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9
```

> I need to draw graphs sharing "id" as X-axis. i.e - f1 vs id, f2 vs id etc.

You need `matplot()`:

```
matplot(x = dat$id, y = rdat, type = "l", lty = 1, col = 1:6, xaxt = "n", xlab = "id")
axis(1, at = dat$id)
```

Read `?matplot` for more.

[image]

Comment: One minor point - `matplot` can handle data.frames just fine  `matplot(dat$id, round(dat[-1], 1), type="l")` for instance

Comment: Many hanks for the solution.Could you provide the same solution using ggplot2?